# Sorting an observable collection with linq

Tags: linq, silverlight, observablecollection

I have an observable collection and I sort it using linq.  Everything is great, but the problem I have is how do I sort the actual observable collection?  Instead I just end up with some IEnumerable thing and I end up clearing the collection and adding the stuff back in.  This can't be good for performance.  Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort ObservableCollection<string> C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112922/sort-observablecollectionstring-c-sharp)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using Silverlight 3.0, then using CollectionViewSource is the cleanest way. Refer below example: (it can be done via xaml as well)

```
ObservableCollection<DateTime> ecAll = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>();
CollectionViewSource sortedcvs = new CollectionViewSource();
sortedcvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Date", 
    System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
sortedcvs.Source = ecAll;
ListBoxContainer.DataContext = sortedcvs;
```

And in corresponding xaml set

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

for the ListBox or any ItemsControl derived control

Answer (score 9):

Since the collection doesn't provide any `Sort` mechanism, this is probably the most practical option. You could implement a sort manually using `Move` etc, but it will probably be slower than doing in this way.

```
    var arr = list.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProp).ToArray();
    list.Clear();
    foreach (var item in arr) {
        list.Add(item);
    }
```

Additionally, you might consider unbinding any UI elements while sorting (via either approach) you only pay to re-bind once:

Interestingly, if this was `BindingList<T>`, you could use `RaiseListChangedEvents` to minimise the number of notifications:

```
    var arr = list.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    bool oldRaise = list.RaiseListChangedEvents;
    list.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
    try {
        list.Clear();
        foreach (var item in arr) {
            list.Add(item);
        }
    } finally {
        list.RaiseListChangedEvents = oldRaise;
        if (oldRaise) list.ResetBindings();
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to go this route, for performance, I'd use `var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProp); list.Clear(); list.AddRange(ordered);` You'll avoid the unnecessary iteration & execution of ToArray() and only do so once during AddRange(). (I'd have to decompile to verify this, since AddRange takes an IEnumerable, it may even just store that without executing it, and then execute & store the flattened collection before any List-specific operations are called. Same performance in the end, but it just defers the cycle hit until later.)

Answer (score 3):

Note that in Linq, you are given an IEnumerable from your query, and that query **has not executed yet**.  Therefore, the following code only runs the query once, to add it to an ObservableCollection:

```
var query = from x in Data
            where x.Tag == "Something"
            select x;

foreach(var item in query)
    MyObservableCollection.Add(item);
```

Take a look at the "[OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx)" extension on IEnumerable:

```
foreach(var item in query.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
    MyObservableCollection.Add(item);
```

Comment: I used this as a base for something similar for my code. I'm starting to think Linq is pretty kick-ass :)

Comment: I am not sure how well this would work if you are getting the ObservableCollection from the WCF service, any advice? Do I need to create a new ObservableCollection on the client and apply "OrderBy" to it? - thanks.

Comment: @VoodooChild: If you already have an ObservableCollection instead of just an IEnumerable, then look at the SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996126/sorting-an-observable-collection-with-linq

Answer (score 3):

ObservableCollections aren't designed to be sortable.  List is sortable, and that's the underlying mechanism used by the answer referencing List.Sort(), but ObservableCollection isn't derived from List so you're out of luck there.  Imo, the "right" solution is not to try to sort the ObservableCollection, but to implement ICollectionView and bind an instance of that to your control.  That interface adds methods for sorting and has the additional benefit that its recognized by Silverlight controls (well, the ones that support it anyway such as DataGrid) so your sorting could be utilized directly from the UI layer.  This question might be helpful:

[Silverlight and icollectionview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975523/silverlight-and-icollectionview)

Answer (score 0):

i followed the link mentioned in this post http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2009/08/04/how-to-sort-observablecollection/comment-page-1/#comment-75

but having issues getting it to work in Silverlight

I created a property public SortableObservableCollection Terms
 When I call Terms.Sort(new TermComparer()) the records are still display unsorted on the UI

could some suggest what could be going wrong. thanks

Comment: you must raise a property changed event on the Terms-property

Answer (score 0):

I found this on CodePlex:

[Sorted Collections](http://softcollections.codeplex.com/)

Haven't used it yet though.

Rick