# Order a ObservableCollection<T> without creating a new one

Tags: c#

I have following code to re-order a `ObservableCollection<T>` collection:

```
list = new ObservableCollection<SomeType>( list.OrderBy( c=>c.Ordinal ) );
```

This code works, but I don't like the fact that "new" is involved. Is there a way I can change the internal element order of a `ObservableCollection<T>` collection without creating a new one?

Thanks,

Comment: A very convoluted approach is available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996126/sorting-an-observable-collection-with-linq).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that `OrderBy` also news up an array to match the size of your collection, and several other objects, you've two choices:

1. Give up on LINQ OrderBy altogether and write your own sort that performs in-place sorting over your ObservableCollection using the Move method.
2. Wait until the current implementation becomes problematic then apply 1.

Don't worry, newing stuff up isn't so terrible. Linq does it all the time. Unless it's a bottleneck, all is good. Unless there's compelling evidence that sorting in-place will really speed up the show, then there's no problem here.

Comment: Especially since the items themselves are not new but only the containing collection. Changing the collection object will also cause INPC bindings to refresh and show the new order.

Comment: The problem with doing this is that you'll loose any observer on the observable collection.

Comment: There are some clients (ex.: Windows Store apps) that animates deleted or moved items in a ObservableCollection, using the events (created, moved, removed, etc.). Recreate the ObservableCollection is pointless!

Answer (score 14):

Implement your custom sort extension method for Observable collection

```
 public static class ObservableCollection
 {
      public static void Sort<TSource, TKey>(this ObservableCollection<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
      {
          List<TSource> sortedList = source.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList();
          source.Clear();
          foreach (var sortedItem in sortedList)
          {
              source.Add(sortedItem);
          }
     }
 }
```

Above answer is inspired by Mr. Jaider's reply to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945461/how-do-i-sort-an-observable-collection/5890134#5890134)

Answer (score 9):

My answer is inspired by  [bkk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973137/order-a-observablecollectiont-without-creating-a-new-one)

```
 public static class ObservableCollection
    {
        public static void Sort<TSource, TKey>(this ObservableCollection<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, bool isAZ)
        {
            if (isAZ)
            {
                List<TSource> sortedList = source.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList();
                source.Clear();
                foreach (var sortedItem in sortedList)
                {
                    source.Add(sortedItem);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                List<TSource> sortedList = source.OrderByDescending(keySelector).ToList();
                source.Clear();
                foreach (var sortedItem in sortedList)
                {
                    source.Add(sortedItem);
                }
            }         
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
 _someObservableCollection.Sort(x => x.Number, false); // Where number is an simple property (non-object)
```

Comment: `isAZ` isn't very intuitive, but this is otherwise an improvement from @bkk's answer. +1

Comment: yeah, I think I'd call it `descending`, but otherwise great answer.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, ObservableCollection has method for moving items inside the collection. You should get a comparer for your T-type, and then use some sorting algorithm

Comment: This is the real answer right here. [ObservableCollection.Move(int,int)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.move?view=net-5.0) can and should be used to implement your own sorting algorithm. Since my observable collections aren't too big, I use Selection Sort to minimize calls to Move, since every call invokes CollectionChanged.