# Bind to a sorted ObservableCollection<T> in a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

I have a list of data objects in my Windows Phone 7 application called `MyObjectList`, which inherits `ObservableCollection<MyObject>`. I keep the list in memory in a public property of `App` called `MyObjects`. My goal is to bind the data to a `ListBox` and have it sorted by `MyObject.Name`.

Currently, I have a `ListBox` in XAML with the name `MyObjectsList` and the following code in the constructor to link it up:

```
public MyObjectListView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MyObjectsList.ItemsSource = ((App)App.Current).MyObjects;
}
```

This works great. I add items to `MyObjects` and they show up in the `ListBox`. However, the data isn't sorted by name when it appears in the list. I tried the following change to get the data to be sorted:

```
this.MyObjectsList.ItemsSource = ((App)App.Current).MyObjects
                                         .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
```

But when I do that, I don't see *any* objects reflected in the `ListBox` sorted or otherwise.

What can I do so that when I add an item to my `ObservableCollection`, it shows up sorted by `.Name` in the `ListBox`?

Comment: Using Linq on an ItemsSource will disable the 'Observable' bit of the ObservableCollection

Answer (score 11):

The problem with your example is the OrderBy method returns an IOrderedEnumerable type of object instead of an ObservableCollection.

Here's something you can do without implementing a custom collection like some of the other answers.

```
var sortedMyObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
foreach (var myobj in ((App)App.Current).MyObjects.Orderby(x => x.Name))
    sortedMyObjects.Add(myobj);
this.MyObjectsList.ItemsSource = sortedMyObjects;
```

The other answers all suggest viable alternatives, but this will solve the problem in the question.

FWIW, in Silverlight 4 there is a PagedCollectionView, but Windows Phone 7's Silverlight is based on Silverlight 3 and that isn't available. I'm only mentioning this to keep you aware of it in anticipation of WP7 eventually updating to SL4.

Comment: This worked awesomely for me!  Converting all of my code to take advantage of this.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a sorted collection instead of your standard `ObservableCollection`. Someone wrote a `SortedObservableCollection` here:

> http://phillters.wordpress.com/2009/05/14/sortedobservablecollection/

Comment: This implementation is really bad since it has a O(n) insertion on a sorted collection. I definitively advice against it.

Comment: I don't think anyone would have a collection large enough as to O(n) being a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't help you for Silverlight, but for WPF 3.5/4, there's a better way to do this involving [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://mokosh.co.uk/post/2009/08/04/how-to-sort-observablecollection/.

It explains how to extend ObservableCollection to expose the underlying Items.Sort() method and then notify listeners that the collection has changed.

Also, [This Post here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975523/silverlight-and-icollectionview) might help you with it. It uses CollectionView.

Comment: The first link you referenced pointed to a great article about using `<CollectionViewSource .../>`.  Once I figured out the right namespaces to use (always a challenge with XAML), it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: The first link appears to be dead